# get camel name out of protocol buffer field

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a protocol buffer message like this:

```
    message Person {

    optional string last_name = 1; 
    optional string first_name = 2;

    }
```

The java generated class looks like this:

```
 public static final class Person extends
      com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage {
    // Use Person.newBuilder() to construct.
    ...... constructor stuffs

    // optional string first_name = 1;
    public static final int FIRST_NAME_FIELD_NUMBER = 1;
    private boolean hasFirstName;
    private java.lang.String firstName_ = "";
    public boolean hasFirstName() { return hasFirstName; }
    public java.lang.String getFirstName() { return firstName_; }

    // optional string last_name = 2;
    public static final int LAST_NAME_FIELD_NUMBER = 2;
    private boolean hasLastName;
    private java.lang.String lastName_ = "";
    public boolean hasLastName() { return hasLastName; }
    public java.lang.String getLastName() { return lastName_; }
  ............
}
```

When java object is generated it uses camel field name as **lastName, firstName** through method call getLastName() and getFirstName(). Is there a way to get the camel field name out? I don't want to get the original field name name : last_name, first_name and convert it again to camel field name every time that I want to do
getter and setter on my java object.

Comment: I am not clear about what you are asking.  Can you post the code for the Java object that is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying in an answer (hence wiki, as not my answer) from Kenton Varda on the [protobuf list](http://groups.google.com/group/protobuf/browse_thread/thread/1cfd1cf9ff1d2ef9/8f3d1f6a0a20af02):

> No, the camel-case name is not stored anywhere.  You will need to construct 
>   it yourself.  If performance is a concern, just cache the results in a 
>   Map.